# Update buttons of org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I know I could use `createButtonsForButtonBar()` to add/remove the new buttons for `WizardDialog` when invoking the dialog. However, I would like the buttons of dialog could change according to the current displayed `WizardPage`.

For example, for page1, I have one new button called "edit". For page2, I have one new button called "move". "edit" should not be displayed when page2 is shown and "move" should be not be displayed when page1 is shown.
Any hints about how could I achieve this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`createButtonsForButtonBar` uses `GridLayout` to layout the buttons with `GridData` set for each button. So should be able to use the `GridData.exclude` flag to exclude buttons for the layout.

To stop displaying a button use something like:

```
Button button = getButton(button id);
GridData data = (GridData)button.getLayoutData();
data.exclude = true;
button.setVisible(false);
```

You will then have to call `layout(true)` on the button bar composite. You may also have to adjust the `numColumns` field of the `GridLayout` for the button bar composite.

You could do this in the `setVisible` method of the wizard pages.